# Count of non-null columns in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table that contains 4 columns and in the 5th column I want to store the count of how many non-null columns there are out of the previous 4. For example:

Where X is any value:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Count
  X     |    X    |   NULL  |    X    |   3
 NULL   |   NULL  |    X    |    X    |   2
 NULL   |   NULL  |   NULL  |   NULL  |   0
```

Comment: Why do you want that ? When do you want that ? Do you want that filled out automatically ?

Comment: Are these string columns?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
select
    T.Column1,
    T.Column2,
    T.Column3,
    T.Column4,
    (
        select count(*)
        from (values (T.Column1), (T.Column2), (T.Column3), (T.Column4)) as v(col)
        where v.col is not null
    ) as Column5
from Table1 as T
```

Comment: @GuilhermeCamposHazan it does, but it could be that it will not work with columns of different types

Comment: hey @RomanPekar, I've never seen that syntax before where you can pull values of column from the same table and rename a table with parenthesis and then call where a table is not null? can you help elaborate what's going on there?

Comment: Well, it's actually standard SQL. You can replace `values` with `select ... union all` if you find it more readable. So basically, for each row we create a fake 'table' with rows containing data from chosen columns and then just run aggregation query on it

Comment: Yes @romanpekar. This doesn't work where the types are different. I have a date and int in the table and it doesn't seem to pull.

Comment: You should better cast values to the same type: `from (values (CAST(T.Column1 AS VARCHAR(1))), (CAST(T.Column2 AS VARCHAR(1))), (CAST(T.Column3 AS VARCHAR(1))), (CAST(T.Column4 AS VARCHAR(1)))) as v(col)`

Answer (score 30):

```
SELECT   Column1,
         Column2,
         Column3,
         Column4,
         CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN Column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN Column4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Column5
FROM     Table
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4,
  Column5 = LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(Column1,1),'')) 
          + LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(Column2,1),''))
          + LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(Column3,1),'')) 
          + LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(Column4,1),''))
 FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Demo:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(a VARCHAR(32),b INT,c VARCHAR(32),d VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x VALUES
('01',3023,NULL,'blat'),
('02',NULL, NULL,'blat'),
('03',5,NULL,'blat'),
('04',24,'bo','blat'),
(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

SELECT a, b, c, d,
    LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(a,1),'')) 
  + LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(b,1),''))
  + LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(c,1),'')) 
  + LEN(COALESCE(LEFT(d,1),''))
 FROM @x;
```

Comment: what I like about this answer is that it's going to work for columns of different types while I can imagine situation when my answer is going to fail for certain combinations of types / values in the columns

Answer (score 1):

That would require you to run an `UPDATE` query for the `Count` column every time any of the rest of the columns are updated or maybe you could set up a trigger if your DB enables you to.

If you're looking to create such a view then the following query would do just fine,

```
SELECT
  Column1,
  Column2,
  Column3,
  Column4,
  (
    COALESCE((CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)
    + COALESCE((CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)
    + COALESCE((CASE WHEN Column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)
    + COALESCE((CASE WHEN Column4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)
  ) AS Count
FROM some_table;
```