# SQL Server Query to count non-null's in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen the solutions here:

[Count of non-null columns in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193365/count-of-non-null-columns-in-each-row)

My own initial instinct was using case statements.  But I have far more than 4 columns and I want to repeat this process on four different tables.  Is there a way to repeat the process with some kind of loop through all columns rather than naming each of them explicitly?

Comment: It would take dynamic sql to do that. Any by the time you have built the dynamic sql you could just code these yourself.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thank you.  My work around now is using select * to get all the column names, then running a concatenate in VBA to build a case statement around each column name.  It is hackish, but it works, and it is quickly reusable as I tinker with the case statement (I may find nulls aren't the only values I want to exclude in my count later on).