# How do you count across rows here? A cell with a Date of Birth should be counted

Tags: sql

| Primary Key | Child1DOB | Child2DOB | Child3DOB | Child4DOB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mother1 | 12.09.00 | 05.04.97 | NULL | NULL |
| mother2 | 09.06.01 | 05.09.98 | 06.04.07 | NULL |
| mother3 | 12.06.02 | 03.14.99 | 06.04.08 | NULL |
| mother4 | 09.07.03 | 05.02.00 | 06.04.09 | NULL |
| mother5 | 10.06.04 | 05.11.12 | 08.05.97 | 01.03.95 |

I basically need to count the amount of children each mother has. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS and add the expected result as second table?

Comment: It seems that's just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193365/count-of-non-null-columns-in-each-row. If not, please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add up 1 for each non-null field:

```
SELECT PrimaryKey, 0+(CASE WHEN Child1DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    +(CASE WHEN Child2DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    +(CASE WHEN Child3DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    +(CASE WHEN Child4DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numChildren
FROM tab
```

or if your NULL values are always found within the last columns, you can check for each column if there's a null or not, and state the number of children directly:

```
SELECT PrimaryKey, 
       CASE WHEN Child4DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 4
            WHEN Child3DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 3
            WHEN Child2DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 2
            ELSE 1 END AS numChildren
FROM tab
```

Both these two queries are likely to work on any DBMS that features the `CASE` statement.