# How to count duplicates based on historical data in SQL?

Tags: sql, duplicates, time-series, databricks

I have a table containing historical data with 2 columns, both strings. For example:

| text | year_month |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | 2023-02 |
| text2 | 2023-02 |
| text3 | 2020-10 |
| text1 | 2019-01 |
| text2 | 2020-01 |

Based on this, for each month, I'd like to count the number of text strings that are duplicates of text strings that appeared in past months. So, for the above example, my output should be:

| year_month | duplicate_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02 | 2 |
| 2020-10 | 0 |
| 2019-01 | 0 |
| 2020-01 | 0 |

How can I do this in SQL?

I could start by joining the input table with itself on an equality condition on text and an inequality condition on year_month. But is there a more efficient direction?

For reference, Databricks SQL is what I'm using for this.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Below is what I was referring to by joining the table with itself. This query works for my data, assuming there are no duplicates within the same month, an assumption I can relax by adding some sort of row ID to the data. See [this link](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fw6xvuvi) for this query in action on a bit more complex version of the example above.

```
SELECT year_month, SUM(is_duplicate) as duplicate_count FROM

  -- Inner query that does self join
  -- It tags a row in the input table as duplicate or not
  (SELECT t1.year_month, t1.text, MAX(CASE WHEN t2.year_month IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS is_duplicate
  FROM input_table t1
  LEFT JOIN input_table t2 ON t1.text = t2.text AND 
  t1.year_month > t2.year_month
  group by t1.year_month, t1.text) as T

GROUP BY year_month
```

Comment: The more efficient direction would be fixing your data and not storing a year and a month as a delimited string - store them as two integer columns or use a proper `date` data type.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. Still, how will approach the query to count duplicates?

Comment: The approach I would use would be to count where qualifying rows `exists` - but the way this would work depends on inequality comparisons so fixing your data first would make sense if you can do it.

Comment: @JonasMetzler If you can't help, let someone else. And you missed my reference to what I tried.

Comment: Well, I think I can help, but proving sufficient effort and explaining why your own attempt went wrong is a must have when asking a question on SO. The downvotes on your question show this. You said "I could start...", but that's very vague and you didn't show a concrete query. Maybe you are looking for something like this?: https://dbfiddle.uk/vbNKfUwQ You have very few sample data, I am not sure whether this would cover all your use cases. As said, you could edit and improve your question...

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thanks for the effort and the dbfiddle website reference (which I wasn't aware existed). I have clarified the question with the exact query I meant earlier in my reference to self join.

For the record, SO community is biased against harder questions, which defeats the purpose of SO. Easier questions get plenty of support, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193365/count-of-non-null-columns-in-each-row. Harder questions get downvoted - "helpers" assume it's OP's fault. Harder questions are harder to pin down by definition. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT year_month, count(nullif(r, 1)) as duplicate_count
  FROM (SELECT text, year_month,
               rank() over (partition by text order by year_month) as r
          FROM input_table) x
 GROUP BY year_month
 ORDER BY year_month DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

With a small tweak [Kombajn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76716930/1191247) will handle the edge case hinted at in your updated question -

> assuming there are no duplicates within the same month

```sql
SELECT `year_month`, COUNT(DISTINCT IF(r > 1, `text`, NULL)) AS duplicate_count
FROM (
    SELECT `text`, `year_month`,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `text` ORDER BY `year_month`) AS r
    FROM input_table
) x
GROUP BY `year_month`
ORDER BY `year_month` DESC;
```

**Note**: `year_month` needs to be quoted in backticks as it is a reserved word (this may not be the case in Databricks SQL).

I think your attempt, with the self left join, can be simplified to remove the derived table:

```sql
SELECT t1.year_month, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.text) AS duplicate_count
FROM input_table t1
LEFT JOIN input_table t2 ON t1.text = t2.text AND t1.year_month > t2.year_month
GROUP BY t1.year_month
ORDER BY t1.year_month DESC;
```

**Note**: `year_month` does not need to be quoted in this query as it is being qualified with the table alias.

The self join will probably benefit from both `` PK (`year_month`, `text`) `` and `` IDX(`text`, `year_month`) ``, whereas Kombajn's query just needs the `PK`.

Try both queries against your data and see how they perform. Use `EXPLAIN` and/or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see how much work the server is having to do to produce the result sets.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZRgRDShh)